# Stata equivalent to R's complete.cases function?

Tags: stata

As in title, I'm trying to locate Stata equivalent to R's `complete.cases` function.

The closest i got so far was to use

```
generate sample = e(sample)
```

after running regression and either deleting cases or using `if` clause on this newl generated variable (solution stolen from [here](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/stata/faq/e_sample.htm)).

Is there any better solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure how exactly you're accustomed to using `complete.cases` in R, but here is an example with application both in R and a Stata equivalent (`rmiss2`):

First, let's make up some data in R for demonstration. We'll save it as a `dta` file that we can use in Stata later on.

```
library(foreign)
set.seed(1)
dat <- data.frame(one = rnorm(15),
                  two = sample(LETTERS, 15),
                  three = rnorm(15),
                  four = runif(15))
dat <- data.frame(lapply(dat, function(x) { x[sample(15, 5)] <- NA; x }))
write.dta(dat, file="completeCases.dta")
```

The data look like this:

```
dat
#           one  two       three      four
# 1          NA    M  0.80418951 0.8921983
# 2   0.1836433    O -0.05710677        NA
# 3  -0.8356286    L  0.50360797 0.3899895
# 4          NA    E          NA        NA
# 5   0.3295078    S          NA 0.9606180
# 6  -0.8204684 <NA> -1.28459935 0.4346595
# 7   0.4874291 <NA>          NA        NA
# 8   0.7383247    C -0.23570656 0.3999944
# 9          NA    N -0.54288826 0.3253522
# 10 -0.3053884 <NA>          NA 0.7570871
# 11         NA    R -0.64947165 0.2026923
# 12  0.3898432 <NA>          NA        NA
# 13         NA    K  1.15191175        NA
# 14 -2.2146999 <NA>  0.99216037 0.2454885
# 15  1.1249309    Q -0.42951311 0.1433044
```

Running `complete.cases` on the data simply gives us a vector of `TRUE`s and `FALSE`s telling us if each row represents a complete case.

```
complete.cases(dat)
#  [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE 
#  [9] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

More often, `complete.cases` is useful for subsetting our data, as in the following:

```
dat[complete.cases(dat), ]
#           one two      three      four
# 3  -0.8356286   L  0.5036080 0.3899895
# 8   0.7383247   C -0.2357066 0.3999944
# 15  1.1249309   Q -0.4295131 0.1433044
```

Or, here, subsetting just based on whether the first three columns are complete.

```
dat[complete.cases(dat[, 1:3]), ]
#           one two       three      four
# 2   0.1836433   O -0.05710677        NA
# 3  -0.8356286   L  0.50360797 0.3899895
# 8   0.7383247   C -0.23570656 0.3999944
# 15  1.1249309   Q -0.42951311 0.1433044
```

---

Now, let's switch to Stata.

First, install `rmiss2` if you don't already have it.

```
. findit rmiss2
```

Second, load the dta file that we created in R.

```
. use "path\to\completeCases.dta", clear
```

Third, we'll use `rmiss2` to generate a new column named "nmis" that tells us how many variables are missing for each case.

```
. egen nmis = rmiss2(one two three four)
. list

     +-----------------------------------------------+
     |       one   two       three       four   nmis |
     |-----------------------------------------------|
  1. |         .     M    .8041895   .8921983      1 |
  2. |  .1836433     O   -.0571068          .      1 |
  3. | -.8356286     L     .503608   .3899895      0 |
  4. |         .     E           .          .      3 |
  5. |  .3295078     S           .    .960618      1 |
     |-----------------------------------------------|
  6. | -.8204684     .   -1.284599   .4346595      1 |
  7. |  .4874291     .           .          .      3 |
  8. |  .7383247     C   -.2357066   .3999944      0 |
  9. |         .     N   -.5428883   .3253522      1 |
 10. | -.3053884     .           .   .7570871      2 |
     |-----------------------------------------------|
 11. |         .     R   -.6494716   .2026923      1 |
 12. |  .3898432     .           .          .      3 |
 13. |         .     K    1.151912          .      2 |
 14. |   -2.2147     .    .9921604   .2454885      1 |
 15. |  1.124931     Q   -.4295131   .1433044      0 |
     +-----------------------------------------------+
```

Finally, we can use `keep if...` to drop cases with missing data.

```
. keep if (nmis == 0)
(12 observations deleted)

. list

     +-----------------------------------------------+
     |       one   two       three       four   nmis |
     |-----------------------------------------------|
  1. | -.8356286     L     .503608   .3899895      0 |
  2. |  .7383247     C   -.2357066   .3999944      0 |
  3. |  1.124931     Q   -.4295131   .1433044      0 |
     +-----------------------------------------------+
```

As with `complete.cases`, you can also specify which columns to check for completeness.

```
. use "path\to\completeCases.dta", clear
(Written by R.              )

. egen nmis = rmiss2(one two three)

. keep if (nmis == 0)
(11 observations deleted)

. list

     +-----------------------------------------------+
     |       one   two       three       four   nmis |
     |-----------------------------------------------|
  1. |  .1836433     O   -.0571068          .      0 |
  2. | -.8356286     L     .503608   .3899895      0 |
  3. |  .7383247     C   -.2357066   .3999944      0 |
  4. |  1.124931     Q   -.4295131   .1433044      0 |
     +-----------------------------------------------+
```

---

#### Update

It should be noted that `keep if...` is "destructive"--you can't get back to your original dataset without reloading your dat file. As such it is safer to use `if` as follows:

```
. summarize one two three four if  nmis == 0

    Variable |       Obs        Mean    Std. Dev.       Min        Max
-------------+--------------------------------------------------------
         one |         3    .3425423    1.038475  -.8356286   1.124931
         two |         3    6.666667    5.507571          1         12
       three |         3   -.0538706    .4924195  -.4295131    .503608
        four |         3    .3110961     .145398   .1433044   .3999944
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Helpful stuff - wasn't aware of `rmiss2` but will add it now to my toolbox =)

Comment: `rmiss2` dates from 1995, and what was distinctive about it then was that it counted missings in string variables as well as numeric. But that was irrelevant then and still is, as string variables can't be included in regressions. The `egen` function `rowmiss()` will count across rows (observations, cases, records) and it also will count missings in string variables. So, Ananda's suggestion works, as it it usually will, because there are no string variables in sight. But you do not need to install `rmiss2`, as the existing `egen` function does just as well.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have it right. I usually see this implemented one of two ways.

```
regress y x1 x2
marksample touse
summarize y x1 x2 if `touse'
```

Or bypass the tempvar `touse` altogether.

```
regress y x1 x2
summarize y x1 x2 if e(sample)
```